# MVC Razor Generator compiled views only working locally

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, gac, razorgenerator

I have created an MVC RazorGenerator compiled view library, ViewLibrary.dll. I have added reference to ViewLibrary.dll in my main MVC app and set the Copy Local attribute to true and the libraries views work great. But when I change the Copy Local to false, none of the library views load.

Ideally, I would like to register the ViewLibrary.dll in my GAC and reference the views across several MVC apps.

Any thoughts or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In the properties of your view, is the Custom Tool set to "RazorGenerator" ?